# start: Job failed to start UWSGI,

Tags: django, ubuntu, uwsgi

Trying to configure ubuntu+nginx+uwsgi+django

upstart script /etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid voxa
setgid www-data

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

uwsgi configuration

```
[uwsgi]
project = project
base = /home/user

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = home/user/Env/project_env
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

But after running the command **sudo service uwsgi start** I get an error

*start: Job failed to start*

What should I check to handle it?

UPD:
with virtualenv enabled app successfully runs with uwsgi command

**uwsgi --http :8000 --module project.wsgi**

Comment: Try to run `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites` from your terminal using user `voxa` and group `www-data`. That will possibly give your some error logs or any reason of fail.

Comment: "!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!"  and  "bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uWSGI doesn't have permissions to create socket file in specified directory. To solve that, you can run emperor as root and drop privileges in vassal, after creating socket. Simply add to your vassal config:

```
username = voxa
gropuname = www-data
```

And remove `setuid` and `setgid` from your upstart config file.

If you're worried that someone will abuse that and use other user/group, you can use emperor [tyrant mode](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html#tyrant-mode-secure-multi-user-hosting), by adding `--emperor-tyrant` to uwsgi start line in upstart config. That will disallow change of username and groupname to other than owner of vassal config file.

Comment: Thanks, it works but only after I've changed  project root folder rights to 777. Is it Ok?

Comment: From security perspective - it's not! If you're sharing your server with someone else or have different projects on it, running on different users, you shouldn't use that. Project files should be owned by user voxa if you're running this project on that user